# Django Change Image Format and Quality

Tags: django, django-models, python-imaging-library

**Django project**

Im trying to compress uploaded images and change their format
Currently it only compresses png images but when a jpg image is uploaded it does not change the format nor does it compress the image

please help sir

**models.py**

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/userpfp/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def compressImageMain(self,image):
        if self.image:

            def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.id:
                    self.image = self.compressImage(self.image)
                super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            def compressImage(self,image):
                imageTemproary = Image.open(image)
                outputIoStream = BytesIO()
                basewidth = 520
                wpercent = (basewidth/float(imageTemproary.size[0]))
                hsize = int((float(imageTemproary.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
                imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize( (basewidth,hsize) )
                imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream , format='PNG', quality=50)
                outputIoStream.seek(0)
                image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream,'ImageField', "%s.png" % image.name.split('.')[0], 'images/userpfp/png', sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
                return image
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the sollution**
first I needed to add: .convert("RGB") when I opened the image
See: [this post](https://medium.com/@ajeetham/image-type-conversion-jpg-png-jpg-webp-png-webp-with-python-7d5df09394c9)

`img = Image.open(image).convert("RGB")`

**To maintain image quality over png and jpef image uploads:**
See: [this post](https://techwiser.com/screenshot-always-saves-png/)
I compressed png to png and saved it as png
and compressed jpeg to jpeg and saved it as jpeg 
(jpg and jpeg are the same)

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class Trade(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/trades/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.image = self.compressImage(self.image)
        super(Trade, self).save()

    def compressImage(self,image):
        img = Image.open(image).convert("RGB")
        im_io = BytesIO()

        if image.name.split('.')[1] == 'jpeg' or image.name.split('.')[1] == 'jpg':
            img.save(im_io , format='jpeg', optimize=True, quality=55)
            new_image = File(im_io, name="%s.jpeg" %image.name.split('.')[0],)
        else:
            img.save(im_io , format='png', optimize=True, quality=55)
            new_image = File(im_io, name="%s.png" %image.name.split('.')[0],)

        return new_image
```